# How to upload Image in localhost database in the form of string from android? Not Path only image

Tags: android

I want to upload my gallery image to localhost database in the form of string from android but i did not found any relevant topic. Please guide me

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert you Image bitmap to base64  String by this code :`

```
`ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```